# Random function keeps generating a dtype

Tags: python, dictionary, random

I'm trying to create a function that generates a dictionary. Dictionary will contain inputs element1 = user will decide input & element2 = is a rng.integers(low, high, size = 50). If I simulate code below, it will return the dictionary + dtype=64.

Question: How do I remove dtype=64, when I would like to keep it as an array?

```
emptydictionary = {}

element2 = rng.integers(1, 10, size = 50)
element1 = 5

def function(element1,element2):
    emptydictionary.update({element1:element2})
    return emptydictionary

function(element1,element2)
```

output is {5: array([5, 7, 5, 3, 7, 9, 3, 8, 3, 7, 8, 5, 7, 3, 1, 1, 5, 9, 2, 5, 7, 2, 7, 3, 8, 6, 5, 2, 5, 8, 1, 7, 5, 7, 6, 4, 3, 6, 2, 6, 1, 6, 6, 1, 7, 4, 8, 1, 2, 5], dtype=int64)}

Comment: You need to add output and expected output to your question. It's very difficult to understand what is happening and what you would like to happen based solely on what you're writing...

Comment: if element 1 = 5; element 2 = rng.integers(1, 10, size = 50), output is {5: array([5, 7, 5, 3, 7, 9, 3, 8, 3, 7, 8, 5, 7, 3, 1, 1, 5, 9, 2, 5, 7, 2,
        7, 3, 8, 6, 5, 2, 5, 8, 1, 7, 5, 7, 6, 4, 3, 6, 2, 6, 1, 6, 6, 1,
        7, 4, 8, 1, 2, 5], dtype=int64)}

Comment: You need to edit your question to add code, as you see the comments aren't suited for it.

Comment: That's just the way numpy prints an array by default.  It's still an array, and it's telling you that the elements are all 64-bit integers.  BTW, `emptydictionary.update({element1:element2})` is the same as `emptydictionary[element1] = element2`, but the second one reads better.

Comment: `element2` is a numpy.ndarray, which has a dtype, which is included in the way it is printed. Note sure why you didn't expect this